# Using a 1 bit variable determine if a number is a numeric palindrome

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I have seen this question in a site that shows interview questions from Google.

I have no idea how to solve this question.

If we are allowed to keep some other variables, then I would suggest to keep 2 indices, 1 point to the beginning and the other to the end. And then use the bit variable to compare the 2 of them (by bit manipulation).

But if we are not allowed to use any more variables, I have no clue how to solve it.

Comment: Search for 'bit twiddling hacks' to find common bit hacks you can use to build this palindrome detector from.

Answer (score 1):

For numbers of 2n bits to be a palindrome it is necessary that each bit at position i equals the bit at index (2n-i).
Using exclusive or (XOR) single bits can easily be compared:
a XOR b == 1 if, and only if, bits a and b are not equal.
So when one compares every corresponding pair of bits (see above) this way and builds the result by ORing all the single-bit comparison results it wil be 0 for palindromes and 1 for any other number.

Comment: How are you going to do all the single-bit comparisons without some sort of for-loop, that uses an index variable?

Comment: I was assuming that n is known and constant. But then again one would not even need the 1-bit variable. One can, on the other hand, re-use the variable the input is stored in and get along without an actual counter.

Comment: So, hardcoding all the comparisons? Ok, fair enough. If you have some concrete algorithm for reusing the input, feel free to post that. But do test it first - there's some hidden complexity, try `10011` for example.

Comment: I wouldn't think `n` is "known and constant", but assuming it has an upper limit is probably fair enough (you can [determine the number of digits using a formula and still hardcode the comparisons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19746734/1711796)).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming we're talking about bit-wise palindromic (i.e. 3 = 11 is, but 2 = 10 is not).

I see there being two possibilities:

(I've written some Java code for each. Some brackets only included for readability)

- **Indices don't count as variables.**

  The first thing I'd say is probably "But indices are variables...".

  We can just loop over the number and return once we get a mismatch.

  `digits` below is a variable, but just for readability - it can trivially be substituted into the if-statement.

  The formula for `digits` came about after some playing around (there may be a simpler way).

  ```java
  boolean isPalidrome(int number)
  {
     int digits = (int)Math.ceil(Math.ceil(Math.log10(1+number)/Math.log10(2)))-1;
     for (int i = 0; number/2 >> i != 0; i++)
     {
        if (((number >> i) & 1) != (((number >> digits - i) & 1)))
           return false;
     }
     return true;
  }
  ```
- **Indices do count as variables.**

  This can be done by essentially unrolling the above loop, assuming we're given a fixed-size number (such as `int`, which is 32 bits).

  I changed the type to `byte` as I didn't really see the point of essentially duplicating that many lines. `byte` only has 8 bits, so we only need 4 checks, with break conditions.

  Again `digits` is a variable, but doesn't need to be.

  ```java
  boolean isPalidrome(byte number)
  {
     int digits = (int)Math.ceil(Math.ceil(Math.log10(1+number)/Math.log10(2)))-1;
     if ((number & 1) != (((number >> digits) & 1)))
        return false;
     if ((number/2 >> 1) == 0)
        return true;
     if (((number >> 1) & 1) != (((number >> (digits - 1)) & 1)))
        return false;
     if ((number/2 >> 2) == 0)
        return true;
     if (((number >> 2) & 1) != (((number >> (digits - 2)) & 1)))
        return false;
     if ((number/2 >> 3) == 0)
        return true;
     if (((number >> 3) & 1) != (((number >> (digits - 3)) & 1)))
        return false;
     return true;
  }
  ```

  The above could also be stuck into a single statement if need be.

  If we're allowed to modify the actual number, it may also be possible to check the first and last bits, as done above, but then modify the number to strip off the first and last bits, so we can just check the first and last bits again, until the number is zero.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/61HNon).

Note how none of the above uses a bit variable. Perhaps the bit variable is simply meant to be a flag to keep track of whether or not the number is a palindrome.

Comment: Regarding the final option raised of modifying the original number ("If we're allowed to modify the actual number..."), this won't work if we can't maintain indices. Consider the binary string 10101. If you drop the first and last 1's, then we're left with (0)10. Unless we have saved indices, we'll think that our 'last bit' is 1 instead of 0 and won't be able to make the comparison correctly.

Comment: @ChaimKut You can always just leave the most significant `1` there, checking and stripping out the 2nd MSB and the LSB instead - perhaps not that easy, but possible.